# Is there a way to show the range of major.minor class versions supported by a jvm?

Tags: jvm, unsupported-class-version

Can the java command print the range of class versions supported by it?
Or is there a list of this information for each jvm version somewhere online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements on supported class file versions are described in [JVM specification §4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-B.2):

```
+---------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+
| Java SE | Corresponding major version | Supported major versions |
+---------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+
| 1.0.2   | 45                          | 45                       |
| 1.1     | 45                          | 45                       |
| 1.2     | 46                          | 45 .. 46                 |
| 1.3     | 47                          | 45 .. 47                 |
| 1.4     | 48                          | 45 .. 48                 |
| 5.0     | 49                          | 45 .. 49                 |
| 6       | 50                          | 45 .. 50                 |
| 7       | 51                          | 45 .. 51                 |
| 8       | 52                          | 45 .. 52                 |
| 9       | 53                          | 45 .. 53                 |
| 10      | 54                          | 45 .. 54                 |
| 11      | 55                          | 45 .. 55                 |
| 12      | 56                          | 45 .. 56                 |
| 13      | 57                          | 45 .. 57                 |
+---------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

> For a class file whose major_version is 56 or above, the minor_version
>   must be 0 or 65535.
>
> For a class file whose major_version is between 45 and 55 inclusive,
>   the minor_version may be any value.
>
> A historical perspective is warranted on JDK support for class file
>   format versions. JDK 1.0.2 supported versions 45.0 through 45.3
>   inclusive. JDK 1.1 supported versions 45.0 through 45.65535 inclusive.
>   When JDK 1.2 introduced support for major version 46, the only minor
>   version supported under that major version was 0. Later JDKs continued
>   the practice of introducing support for a new major version (47, 48,
>   etc) but supporting only a minor version of 0 under the new major
>   version. Finally, the introduction of preview features in Java SE 12
>   (see below) motivated a standard role for the minor version of the
>   class file format, so JDK 12 supported minor versions of 0 and 65535
>   under major version 56. Subsequent JDKs introduce support for N.0 and
>   N.65535 where N is the corresponding major version of the implemented
>   Java SE Platform. For example, JDK 13 supports 57.0 and 57.65535.